# Can I give up on await after some time, on async Rust?

Tags: rust

Normally on async Rust, when I want to poll a Future until it returns, I do

```
let s = my_function().await;
```

The runtime will poll it efficiently, but it will also block the current thread until it finishes.

What if I want a poll that can be canceled? Example:

```
pub fn play(client: Arc<Mutex<Client>>) {
    client.lock().unwrap().my_thread = std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        do_something().await;
        do_something_2().await;
        do_something_3().await;
    });
}
```

I might call `my_client.play()` and a thread could be launched. Note that `my_client` still owns the thread. What if I want to destruct `my_client`, but the thread is still going?

Is there a way to `await` for a result, but keep looking into a variable every 100ms to see if I should give up on `await`?

Comment: You could repeatedly `await` on something wrapped within a 100ms timeout.

Comment: It depends on your runtime. Tokio has [`timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html) which may be what you want.

Comment: You could invert the cancel logic and give the `my_client.play()` future a shutdown listener that you would fire externally. A simple pattern to get a shutdown listener is to use a `oneshot::channel` and concurrently `select` that in the loop that keeps the `my_client.play()` thread going. If you're using `tokio`, `spawn()` detaches the task, so it keeps running even when the handle is dropped. Recent `tokio` versions have added support for task cancellation.